# AWS Glue: why, when I edit a script, does it also create a "my_script.temp" object in the S3 bucket? Is it safe to remove?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have some ETL jobs on AWS glue. I noticed that whenever I edit or create a script and then save it, it saves 2 objects in the script bucket: the actual script AND the same object with a '.temp' extension.

Is this temp extension needed or can I safely remove it? I know it doesn't hurt nobody, but I'm pretty OCD about keeping my buckets clean from unnecessary objects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not in the middle of making modifications to the script you can delete it but it's a pointless exercise as this file is created each time you click edit script in the console.